# background-color applies only to part of a div in bootstrap , when it should apply to the whole div

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap-3, background-color

I have a form in a website I am building with the following html using Bootstrap

```
<div class="hotel-search side-menu blue-background ">
      <h2>Search</h2>
      <hr/>
      <br/>
     <form class="hotel-search-form">
        <div class="form-group  col-md-12">
          <label for='nationanlity'>Nationality</label>
          <select class="chosen form-control"  name="nationanlity" placeholder="Please select your nationality">
                <option value="">Select Nationality</option>
                <option value="...">...</option>
          </select>
        </div>
       <div class="form-group col-sm-6">   
          <select class="chosen form-control" id="country" name="country" placeholder="Please select your country">
                 <option value="">Select Country</option>
                 <option selected="selected" value="UAE">UAE</option>
           </select>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group col-sm-6">

           <select class="chosen form-control" id="city" name="city"     placeholder="Please select your city">
                   <option value="">Select City</option>        
           </select>
       </div>

      <div class="form-group  col-md-12">
           <label for="hotel">Hotel Name</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hotel"     placeholder="Hotel Name">
          </div>
</form>
```

The only css that applies to this form is the from the 
    .blue-background {
        background-color: #010118;
    }
css. My problem is that this will only set the background color for part of the form

[image: image file]([![https://www.dropbox.com/s/ahxlkc9pixm49x8/stackoverflow.PNG?dl=0]

This has happened a few time before, and it works fine when I add .row to the main div, but that causes the alignment to go bad, can anyone explain to me why is this is happening? and a possible solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
display:table;
```

to the main form div seems to solve the problem, but I have no idea why it does not work without it.

Answer (score 0):

```
display: inline-block; also works.
```

Additionally you forgot to close the form and the last div, but that does not solve the problem in question.

Comment: thanks, I edited the code to close the form and div, it was error in formatting the question.